# Is it possible to use HTC Vive Focus controllers while Vive Focus Plus controllers are still not added in A-FRAME?

Tags: aframe, htc-vive, webxr

I am working on a project with A-FRAME and a Vive Focus Plus headset and since the Vive Focus Plus are still not included in A-FRAME I was thinking of using some other HTC controller instead.
When I used the laser-controls component a vive focus controller appears but I can not get to show two of them. Whenever I use:

```
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
<a-entity laser-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
```

it only shows the last defined hand (left or right) with the controller.

I've also tried to use:

```
<a-entity vive-focus-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
<a-entity vive-focus-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
```

and

```
<a-entity vive-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
<a-entity vive-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
```

but then no controller appears.

I'm using A-FRAME 1.0.4 and the vive focus plus profile is already included in the webxr input profiles registry.

Also I am using the Firefox Reality APP form inside the Vive Focus Plus headset.

Comment: Does your browser ships WebXR? Is it supporting the Vive Focus Plus controllers?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Firefox Reality that comes installed in the Headset, I just added that info also in the question.

Comment: FTI, Firefox has not yet shipped WebXR

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it did, but anyways in the firefox browser I do get both correct controllers and that changes when I enter VR mode in A-FRAME, is it possible that it is still an issue with Firefox?